# HTML/JS: setting file property of file input

Tags: javascript, file, video, activexobject, fso

I've been looking into fso in JS, and was wondering if it was possible to get and play a video locally stored on the client machine, with just the path saved in a database?

the following example would imply a local web application running on IIS (or something symilar).

uploading the video and putting it into a database, but the client might have limited space to work with so encoding the video in base64 and appending it to the database would be impractical. so an invisible file input to which I can set the file would be the best sollution (since the application has to also work offline, so youtube is not an option).

**tl;dr**
would there be a way to set the `file` propterty of an `<input type="file">` with just a path to a video/audio file?

**What I have now**

```
function watchvid(location) {
    var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    //reading and appending the video here
    file.Close();
}
```

Comment: No you can't ,browser won't allow that due to security concerns.But why use `<input type='file'>` when you have `<video>`,`<iframe>` and `<embed>` available ?

Comment: well shoot, the video is on a local disk, but not neccecairely in the root of the site.